# How to integrate GWT with grails?

Tags: grails, gwt

I have been facing issue while compiling gwt modules with **grails 2.5.6**.

**Please refer below error**

[image: error_image]

**Please refer below jar files related to GWT which are being used in my application**

[image: jar_image]

**Please refer below  **BuildConfig.groovy** file content**

```
 gwt {
     version="2.8.0"
 }

plugins {
    // plugins for the build system only
    build ":tomcat:7.0.70" // or ":tomcat:8.0.22"

    // plugins for the compile step
    compile ":scaffolding:2.1.2"
    compile ':cache:1.1.8'
    // asset-pipeline 2.0+ requires Java 7, use version 1.9.x with Java 6
    compile ":asset-pipeline:2.5.7"

    // plugins needed at runtime but not for compilation
    runtime ":hibernate4:4.3.10" // or ":hibernate:3.6.10.18"
    runtime ":database-migration:1.4.0"
    runtime ":jquery:1.11.1"
    runtime "org.grails.plugins:resources:1.2.14"

    build ":extended-dependency-manager:0.5.5"
    compile ":gwt:1.0-SNAPSHOT", {
        transitive=false
    }

    // Uncomment these to enable additional asset-pipeline capabilities
    //compile ":sass-asset-pipeline:1.9.0"
    //compile ":less-asset-pipeline:1.10.0"
    //compile ":coffee-asset-pipeline:1.8.0"
    //compile ":handlebars-asset-pipeline:1.3.0.3"
}
```